# How to make an inventory system with hover and active effects

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, inventory

I'm making an inventory system and I can't find the best way to go about making the strucure.
I'm using JQuery .draggable and .droppable and my html is like this:

```
<div id="inventory">
  <div class="slot" data-slot_id="1">
      <div class="item ui-draggable" data-item_id="1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slot" data-slot_id="2"></div>
  <div class="slot" data-slot_id="3"></div>
</div>
```

My inventory has a background image and when a draggable item hovers over a slot it highligts my problems is that because the draggable item is inside a div the divs that are after the one it is in appear ontop of the draggable item. I don't how to make this work with the highlight without it covering the draggable item.

One last thing the slots are floating to the left in the container because the inventory container can change size and I need the slots to automatically re order and fit in the inventory. Any advice would be great thanks!

Thaiscorpion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey just found the solution, quite easy hehe I blame the late night:
On the start Drag event make the parent item have a higher index so its children stay ontop of the rest then on the drop event set it back to normal, workds great :D